# How to show seaborn plots next to each other? Using pyplot-style (not OO)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want show three plots with the same data but in different kinds of plots.

The following Code would show them one below the other:

```
plt.figure()

sns.displot(t['Age'], kind="kde", rug = True)

sns.displot(t['Age'], kind="hist", bins = 25)

sns.displot(t['Age'], kind="ecdf")

plt.show()
```

With pyplot plots and the none-OO style i could do something like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

plt.subplot(131)
plt.hist(t['Age'], bins = 22)

plt.subplot(132)
plt.hist(t['Age'], bins = 33)

plt.subplot(133)
plt.hist(t['Age'], bins = int(t['Age'].max() - t['Age'].min()))

plt.show()
```

Which looks perfectly nice.
[Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQ9n.png)

Why cant i just do this?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

plt.subplot(131)
sns.displot(t['Age'], kind="kde", rug = True)
plt.subplot(132)
sns.displot(t['Age'], kind="hist", bins = 25)
plt.subplot(133)
sns.displot(t['Age'], kind="ecdf")

plt.show()
```

This looks terrible
[How it looks... it seems like they are stuck in the left border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Uue.png)

Is it possible to do that without this oo notation?

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3)
sns.displot(..., ax=ax1)
sns.displot(..., ax=ax2)
...
```

Comment: No, because there is no `ax` parameter. [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) is a  [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid). Please read the documentation.

Comment: For your desired usage, use [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot), which has `ax`.

Comment: i'm curious why you're trying to avoid the OO interface

Comment: Very interesting, Thank you very much @TrentonMcKinney

Answer (score 1):

okok, in consequence of a short but very enlightening study of the seaborn [api](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html) i get to a conclusion:

displot() is very flexible and you can do many kinds of graphs, which have interestingly each its own functions.

you can do something like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))

plt.subplot(141)
sns.kdeplot(t['Age'])
plt.subplot(142)
sns.histplot(t['Age'])
plt.subplot(143)
sns.ecdfplot(t['Age'])
plt.subplot(144)
sns.rugplot(t['Age'])

plt.show()
```

to avoid OO-Style.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg0G0.png)

But in this case its not that easy to get the rugplot andd the kde plot to the same axes. When you try:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

plt.subplot(131)
sns.kdeplot(t['Age'])
plt.subplot(132)
sns.histplot(t['Age'])
plt.subplot(133)
sns.ecdfplot(t['Age'])
plt.subplot(131)
sns.rugplot(t['Age'])

plt.show()
```

[You get this warning:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GReX.png)
So you shouldnt use it because of this warning.

If you want to make it look beautiful you need more controol and OO-Style is probably best solution:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(12,4))

sns.kdeplot(t['Age'], ax = axes[0])
sns.histplot(t['Age'], ax = axes[1])
sns.ecdfplot(t['Age'], ax = axes[2])
sns.rugplot(t['Age'], ax = axes[0])

plt.show()
```

[Very nice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZzyA.png)